Conversion of HTML templates to WordPress block theme
Conversion of HTML templates to WordPress classic theme is not so hard task as I know but recently WordPress launch a new theming system called block theme in which templates are made from a visual editor. Say I have templates having complex structure which include many CSS stylings and so many JavaScript effects. Can I convert these templates to block theme.
